# download google document for android, error 403, only binary file can download

Tags: google-sheets-api

How can I export files like `application/document`, `application/spreadsheet` and then download them? I get the following error:

> 403 : only binary file can download, use google export**

```
if (file.mimeType.contains("document") ||
    file.mimeType.contains("spreadsheet") ||
    file.mimeType.contains("archive") ||
    file.mimeType.contains("text"))
{

    val fileData = FileData(file.name, file.webContentLink ?: "", size
        , isDir = false, extension = file.fileExtension, createdAt = file.createdTime.value.toString())
    fileData.url = Uri.parse(file.webContentLink ?: "")

    ApiDriveHelper.getInstance().readFile(file.id, file.name).addOnCompleteListener {
        Log.e("<<<thanhdocument", "downloaded")
    }.addOnFailureListener({
        Log.e("<<<download fail", it.localizedMessage)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Google documents can only be stored on Google Drive, not locally

To download you have to convert them to a [compatible mime type](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats) and use  for this the the Drive API method [export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export), as explained in the [Download a Google Document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_google_document) documentation.